# Can't get subview animation to appear even after alloc :)

Tags: xcode

I have a subview loaded into an UIView.  In the subview's .m file I have the following:

```
- (void)startAnimation {

 // Array to hold png images
 imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:22];
 animatedImages = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:viewForImage];

 // Build array of images, cycling through image names
 for (int i = 1; i < 22; i++){
  [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png", i]]];
 }

 animatedImages.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithArray:imageArray];

 // One cycle through all the images takes 1 seconds
 animatedImages.animationDuration = 2.0;

 // Repeat forever
 animatedImages.animationRepeatCount = 0;

 // Add subview and make window visible
 [viewForMovie addSubview:animatedImages];

 // Start it up
 animatedImages.startAnimating;

   NSLog(@"Executed");

 }
```

Please be noted that I have in the .h file:

```
UIImageView *animatedImages;
NSMutableArray *imageArray;
UIView *viewForMovie;

@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIView *viewForMovie;
```

and in the .m file:

```
@synthesize viewForMovie;
```

and I have connected viewForMovie to a UIView in IB.  I've been on this for several hours now and have tried many variations I've found on the web but cannot get it to work.  There are no errors and the other GUI graphics in the subview appear very nicely....but the animation just doesn't appear over top where it should.  Also the NSlog reports that the method has in fact been called from the parent.  Can anyone see any blaring issues?  Thx.
PS: I'm pretty new at this.

Comment: Show how the animatedImages object is created (edit the question and add the code to it).

Comment: I have a feeling I'm missing something...because I thought that UIImageView *animatedImages; was creating it and
[viewForMovie addSubview:animatedImages]; was adding it.

Comment: No, that's just a declaration.  Are you instantiating animatedImages (doing alloc+initWithImage on it) anywhere?

Comment: No, dang. I'll add that and report back.

Comment: Ok, edit the question when you have an update so it gets visibility.

Comment: So, viewForImage is a UIImage declared/synthesized and connected in IB.  Still no animation...unless I did that part wrong. (Thanks for your quick responses btw)

Comment: Sorry not able to give a full answer right now but after alloc+init, set its frame (size and position) like this: `animatedImages.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,300,300);`.

Comment: Alright....that is in as well and still no animation.  I did however start to get a warning about calling that method from the parent of subview. 'UIView' may not respond to '-startAnimation'

Comment: I call the function from the parent with [newView startAnimation];  newView points to the subview and the NSLog still prints out it's message, meaning that the method did in fact get called, no?  Could that be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code shown and the behavior you see so far, here are my suggestions:

1. Make sure the viewForMovie IBOutlet is connected properly in Interface Builder.  If it's not connected properly (and so nil), nothing will appear.  If you didn't mean to make it an IBOutlet in the first place, then you'll need to manually create it and add it as a subview to `self` before using it.
2. Not sure why you have the viewForMovie UIView in the first place.  Is this subview's class (let's call it MySubview) a subclass of UIView?  You can just show the animation in `self` instead of adding another subview inside it.  Are you going to add more uiviews to this subview besides the viewForMovie?
3. To get rid of the "may not respond to" warning, declare the startAnimation method in the MySubview.h file (under the @property line):
   `-(void)startAnimation;`
4. The fact that the warning says "***UIView*** may not respond" also tells you that the parent view has declared newView as a UIView instead of MySubview (or whatever you've named the subview class).  Change the declaration in the parent from `UIView *newView;` to `MySubview *newView;`.
5. In the initWithImage, what is "viewForImage"?  Is it a UIImage variable or something else?
6. If all of the images are the same size and fit in the subview as-is, you don't need to set the frame--the initWithImage will automatically size the UIImageView using the init-image dimensions.
7. Double check that the images you are referencing in the for-loop are named exactly as they are in the code and that they have actually been added to the project.
8. Finally, you should release the objects you alloc in startAnimation.  At the end of the method, add:
   `[imageArray release];

   [animatedImages release];`

The only item, however, that I think is actually preventing the animation from appearing right now is item 1.

Comment: Thanks aBitObvious!  I followed your steps here exactly and everything ended up working fine.  Thanks for your responses.